# Is there a way to update custom fields with a post function in JIRA?

Tags: jira

I was wondering if there is a way to update a custom field during a workflow transition in JIRA.

The "Update Issue Field" post function is the closest feature I found, but its document explicitly states "This post function cannot update custom fields and must be positioned after the other optional post functions."

I was wondering if there is another function can support my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JIRA Suite Utilities is the standard add-on everyone uses to do this

https://jsutil.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JSUTIL/JIRA+Suite+Utilities+Workflow+Post-Functions#JIRASuiteUtilitiesWorkflowPost-Functions-UpdateIssueCustomFieldPost-Function

Not available for OnDemand

**EDIT:** [JIRA Suite Utilities](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities/cloud/installation) is now available for JIRA Cloud and comes pre-installed in new Cloud instances.

**EDIT:** And now it is no longer free.

Comment: Not free, but not very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Post Function `Update Issue Custom Field` now in JIRA OnDemand 7.1. It seems to be pretty limited, e.g. you can't write an expression such as setting the value if it's currently empty.

I'd provide a link to their documentation page but their search claims it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is possible to execute Groovy script as Post Function and it let you do almost everything.
For example, [here](https://github.com/hrabosch/atlassian-products/blob/master/jira/scripts/updateCfDependentOnOtherCf.groovy) is script, how to update custom field (option) dependent on value of another custom field value.
EDIT: This solution is abel only for hosted instace. Not for Cloud

Comment: You can't use groovy scripts in cloud version.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I forgot. I edited answer to clarify it.